# Levenberg-Marquardt in Julia Non-Linear Least Squares packages

Tags: julia, nonlinear-optimization

I have a parametric estimation problem which can be solved by Non-Linear Least Squares optimization. I have an analytical model with two unknown parameters `x[0]` and `x[1]`. I have a vector of my measured data samples, using which I write the `cost function`.

```
function cost_function(x)
    measured = data_read()   # This is where I read my measured samples
    model = analytical_model(x)  # I calculate the values from my 
                                   analytical model method
    residual = abs.(measured - model)
    return residual
end
```

In `LsqFit` [package](https://github.com/JuliaNLSolvers/LsqFit.jl)
in Julia, which has the `Levenberg-Marquardt (LM)` implementation, there is only the method `curve_fit` which takes in `model` (`analytical_model()` here), `xdata`, `p`, `ydata` and it passes this function to the `LM` optimizer. (i.e) `model(xdata,p) - ydata` becomes the residual. But for me, my `measured` and `model` are both complex numbers and that is the reason I have to return the `abs.()`.

I have tried

```
import LsqFit
result = LsqFit.levenberg_marquardt(cost_function, rand(2))
```

but it requires the jacobian of my `cost_function(x)` as another argument. I do not know the Jacobian and I want my optimizer to calculate the Jacobian for me using Forward Difference approximation. Is there a way to do this in Julia?

Comment: Probably the simplest is to use https://github.com/JuliaNLSolvers/Optim.jl and return `sum(residual)` from your function. Note that Julia uses 1-based indexing, so probably you have `x[1]` and `x[2]`.

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński, thanks for your response. I did try the Optim.jl package - they don't have `Levenberg-Marquardt` function implemented in this. The closest quadratic non-linear optimizer I found was `NewtonTrustRegion()` which does not work efficiently for me. Regarding the indexing, I am a python user and I am slowly shifting to Julia. But I did use `x[1]` and `x[2]` in my code though.. :)

Comment: Why do you strictly require L-M optimizer? In LsqFit.jl you have `curve_fit` function in which you do not have to pass Jacobian and can choose forward difference approximation via `autodiff` kwarg.

Comment: As I said earlier, I looked through the `curve_fit` code which does what I mention in the summary. In LsqFit package in Julia, which has the Levenberg-Marquardt (LM) implementation, there is only the method curve_fit which takes in `model (analytical_model() here)`, `xdata`, `p`, `ydata` and it passes this function to the LM optimizer. (i.e) `model(xdata,p) - ydata` becomes the residual. But I want `abs.(model(xdata,p) - ydata)` to be input to the residual.

Comment: OK - now I get it. Sorry for missing the comment. I have posted what I think should work (assuming that you are working with `Float64` values; if they are e.g. `BigFloat` then change the third argument accordingly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following call should work:

```
LsqFit.lmfit(cost_function, [0.5, 0.5], Float64[])
```

(please let me know if it worked, `[0.5, 0.5]` is an example starting point)

Here is an example:

```
julia> function cost_function(x)
           measured = [2:2:20;] .+ 0.5im
           model = [1:10;] .* x[1] .+ x[2] .* im
           residual = abs.(measured .- model)
           return residual
       end
cost_function (generic function with 1 method)

julia> LsqFit.lmfit(cost_function, [0.5, 0.5], Float64[])
LsqFit.LsqFitResult{Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,2},Array{Float64,1}}([2.0, 0.5], [5.18665e-8, 5.36734e-8, 5.65567e-8, 6.03625e-8, 6.49286e-8, 7.01067e-8, 7.57714e-8, 8.18218e-8, 8.81784e-8, 9.47796e-8], [0.000658313 -0.00846345; 0.00131663 -0.00846342; … ; 0.00592487 -0.00846286; 0.00658318 -0.00846272], true, Float64[])

julia> LsqFit.lmfit(cost_function, [0.5, 0.5], Float64[], autodiff=:forward)
LsqFit.LsqFitResult{Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,1},Array{Float64,2},Array{Float64,1}}([2.0, 0.5], [4.44089e-16, 8.88178e-16, 1.77636e-15, 1.77636e-15, 1.77636e-15, 3.55271e-15, 3.55271e-15, 3.55271e-15, 3.55271e-15, 3.55271e-15], [-1.0 -0.0; -2.0 -0.0; … ; -9.0 -0.0; -10.0 -0.0], true, Float64[])
```

and we see that a correct solution `[2.0, 0.5]` is returned.